# Center Hikes Ball- Football

Tags: american-football, quarterback

Question here. I know quite a bit about football but don't actually know this specific rule. 
Here is the scenario:

1. QB says "Ready Set Hike"
2. Center lifts ball of ground to hand to QB
3. QB acts like he took the snap and runs to the right to mimic a QB sneak
4. Running Back quickly grabs the hiked ball from between the Centers legs and runs.

Is this a legal play with respect to standard American Football regulations?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the running back isn't on the line, it doesn't seem to be prohibited under NFL rules. However, the way you described it wouldn't work because it's highly unlikely the running back would have enough time to grab the ball from under center before the defense could get there. Normally, it would be a direct snap to the running back.